# Trying to get the right diagonal of a matrix results in a "vector out of range" error

Tags: c++, c++14

I have this code where I am trying to take the diagonal elements from a matrix stored in a vector from the top right, but I get a "vector out of range" error

```
     const int size_rows = 3;
     const int size_cols = 3;

    vector< vector<int> > matrixs(size_rows, vector<int>(size_cols)); //multidimensional vector
    for (size_t i = size_rows - 1; i >= 0; )
        {
            for (size_t j = 0; j < size_cols; j++)
            {
                cout << matrixs[i][j] << " ";

                i--;
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
```

if my input is this matrix

```
4 9 2
3 5 7
8 1 5
```

I should get this output:

```
2,5,8
```

But I get an error stating **vector subscript out of range!**
how can I fix this ?

Comment: `i >= 0;` is not a correct condition for `size_t` since it is unsigned, when you reach 0 and decrement again, it will likely yield a very high number and index incorrectly.

Comment: okay so i just changed it to `int` and it worked 
thanks

Comment: @Borgleader: Answers go in the answer section. Thanks

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You already did that for me thanks. + it's not a full answer as I havent bothered to explain how to fix it.

Comment: @Borgleader: Okay then don't write it. If it were wrong we would not be able to downvote. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (size_t i = size_rows - 1; i >= 0; )
```

Your loop runs forever, because an unsigned value is *always* greater than or equal to 0, and `size_t` is unsigned. Once you reach 0 and subtract, you'll wrap around to the highest possible value of `size_t`, which is well out of range of your vector.

Running your program in a debugger would have revealed this.

Iterating towards zero with an unsigned value is tricky business. You might be better off iterating upwards but adjusting your counter for use:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < size_rows; ) {
   const size_t real_i = size_rows - 1 - i;
   // now use real_i instead
   i--;
}
```

Alternatively you could switch from `size_t` to `ssize_t` (or just `int`).

Comment: i really didn't know size_t is unsigned 
visual studio just auto generates it when ever i write a `for` loop so i assumed it was correct so i changed it to int it worked fine :) thanks

Comment: @droidfiji: Simply Googling `size_t` would have revealed this.

Comment: i really didn't know that was the problem

Comment: @droidfiji: Right, but you would have known if you'd done some research, which is something we expect you to do on your own before resorting to asking us. Stack Overflow should not be your first port of call.